# In Python I'm trying to import a text file into a dictionary but only assign the key, no value

Tags: python

Is there a way to import a text file and assign the key without a value? Im doing so to import other values from another text file to assign them as the values for the key.

For example, I would get a name from one text file and assign it as a key, then get their bank accnt number, amount of money, id number from another text file and assign those values to the key.

I know how to import text files WITH the key and value from a single text file, but i dont know how to do it separately and assign it to one key value pair.

Thanks.

Comment: Code you tried and example input file would be useful and expected output.

Comment: As far as the first element to your question -- just assign it a dummy/mock value? As far as the second element to your question -- read the Python documentation for dictionaries to learn how to assign new values to keys.

Answer (score 1):

Every `dict` has a value for every key -- no such thing as "no value" for one or more keys.  However you can set the value to a placeholder, e.g `None`, and then simply reassign it once you know exactly what the value for each given key you want to be.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to assign a key without value or vice versa in a dict. But you can override a value to a given key, so:

```
d["name"] = None
[...]
d["name"] = data
```

will work.

On the other hand, if you don't want to do this you can just save the key (or data) in a temporary variable:

```
temp_dict_entry = [None, None]
temp_dict_entry[0] = "name"
[...]
temp_dict_entry[1] = data
[...]
d[temp_dict_entry[0]] = temp_dict_entry[1]
```

The way I've written it here is not good, but could be useful depending on context (maybe). For example this will work if you know the data before you know the key, which will not work with the first solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a place-holder value when you first read in the would-be keys. For example, if your intended value will be a 3-tuple of bank account number, amount of money, and id number, you could represent an "unfilled" value as `(None, None, None)`.

In the code, this means when you are attempting to place a key into the `dict` for the first time, you just place `(None, None, None)` as the value:

```
some_dict = {}
with open('some_file.txt', 'r') as the_file:
    for line in the_file.readlines():
        key_name = compute_key_name(line)
        some_dict[key_name] = (None, None, None) # place holder
```

Then later when you read the actual value, you can do

```
with open('some_other_file.txt', 'r') as the_other_file:
    for line in the_other_file.readlines():
        key_name, bank_acct, money, id_num = compute_info(line)
        some_dict[key_name] = (bank_acct, money, id_num)
```

where I've used some made up functions `compute_key_name` and `compute_info` to represent whatever arbitrary file-processing logic might occur in your loops prior to the point when you're ready to write data into the `dict`.